# openWithCompletionHandler never calls completion block in iPhone5

Tags: ios, uidocument

Recently I run into a strange problem and I'd be interested, if somebody has experienced the same. I'm working on an iCloud-enabled application, which uses

- (void)openWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionHandler

for some files, which are stored in iCloud.

I'm using XCode 4.5.2 (4G2008a) and I have several devices, each running iOS 6.0.1: an iPhone 3GS, 4GS,5, several iPads and 2 iPod Touch, 4th and 5th generation. In addition I'm using some MAC's that also deal with the iCloud data - however, they use a different scheme to access the files.

Now the problem: Except on the iPhone 5, the app is working perfectly on all other devices - the completion handler is called and the document loaded and opened correctly, no matter what other devices run the app at the same time.

However, on the iPhone 5 neither the completion block nor loadFromContents:: is ever called, and the app just hangs, because it depends on this file if iCloud reports it to tbe an ubiquitous item that exists.

As the same app runs on all other devices, I assume, there shouldn't be any coding or logic error but some differences in the iPhone 5 iOS implementation. Has anybody similiar experiences, or an idea for a workaround?

Comment: Same issue here, iOS6.